# Emulate Mifare Ultralight without HCE

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I need to emulate Mifare Cards.
I've struggled with this about few days and, of course, found some interesting.
Like:

- [quite similar question, but not enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588626/emulate-mifare-smart-card-on-nfc-device-with-nxp-chip)
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396659/why-doesnt-android-hce-support-mifare-classic-type?rq=1)
- [and of course this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055497/emulate-mifare-card-with-android-4-4)

But I've not seen info about how to emulate WITHOUT secure element.
mifare ultralight is secure nightmare and we don't have to have SE.
Furthermore, I've seen many times answers where people told android with NFC can emulate mifare ultralight (but without any detail).

Well, to be brief, I have 2 question:

1. Is it possible, to emulate mifare ultralight with a phone without HCE.
2. If not, why devices can not emulate the card (because the card supports ISO/IEC 14443-3 only), but can read that?
3. If it is, what UID does a phone have without HCE (lenth, is that constant).

Comment: Hi, did you dind any solution? I need also to emulate a mifare Ultralight card on android, only to send its content and receive new content.

Comment: This question is unclear and does not make sense: At first, you list a few Q/A explaining why emulation of MF Ultralight is currently not possible using HCE on Android. But then you ask if it would be possible to emulate the card without a secure element (since it might not be needed). Yet, that's exactly what HCE would be supposed to do -> emulation *without* a secure element. Hence, it's *not* possible without an SE. Finally, you ask if emulation would be possible without HCE (this would make sense in the context of your links), but this would then mean you *do* want to use an SE.